# Do multiple JDBC connections in a distributed transaction for one SQL Server database require DTC?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, msdtc

I want to launch multiple JDBC connections that write to a single database table in a distributed transaction (e.g. each one runs `conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,2,3)"`). In other words, if one of those connections fails, I want none of my connections to commit. Does this require DTC?

From what I’ve been reading, DTC is necessary when there multiple physical nodes or database instances are involved, but I haven’t been able to find anything that explicitly speaks about multiple connections to a single table.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: And then answer is that it would require a DTC, as the connections are independent and there is no way to have a transaction span more than one.